# Can't edit TextBlock Text with caliburn micro dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

This might have been answered before.
I am trying to edit my TextBlock dynamically from an object that has a string.
However. It doesn't seem to be updated from the View. But the value is updated. Just that it doesn't display it. Is there any way for that? Is there a repaint method?

What should I do?

Code:

ViewModel:

```
private String title = "";

public string Title { get { return title; }
    set
    {
        title = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Title);
    }
}
```

View.XAML:

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" 
                   Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   Grid.Row="2" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   FontSize="18" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                   TextAlignment="Center" 
 FontWeight="Light"/>
```

Comment: have you tried debugging. Seting breakpoint on line `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Title);`

Comment: yes I have. The value changes. But it doesn't get displayed

Comment: is the DataContext of the TextBlock set correctly? Debugging binding should be possible. set breakpoint on line `Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: I'm going to make a guess that your Binding is incorrect. Check the **Output Window**, I'd bet that you have a binding error in there. This should give you a good indication of where the problem lies.

Comment: No errors about binding or no error at all

Comment: The value has changed. But to get it to display it on the view is the main problem here

Comment: do you have logging turned on? in your BootStrapper Configure() method? ````LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLog(type);```` it would definitely point to a binding or even viewmodel issue.

Comment: Any chance you're attempting to update the value using the lower case backing field by accident?

Comment: No it is not lower case. it was a typo when I wrote the question. No results though. The thing is. I am passing a string from another ViewModel to that one and it doesn't seem to get updated.

Comment: Doing log. it seems to invoke fine. no binding errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the solution here is to use Caliburns EventAggregator to communicate with several VM. This was the solution I came up with and now it works :)